# Getting GET http://localhost:4200/null 404 (Not Found) in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on an angular app using ng9.

I have a div in which I want to set an avatar using using an image from the api.
In the component.ts

```
....

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  nextLaunch$: Observable<SpacexNext>;

  panelOpenState: true;

  search = '';

  constructor(
    private spacexService: SpacexService,
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
    ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.nextLaunch$ = this.spacexService.getNextLaunch();
    }
    
...
```

in the .html

```
<div mat-card-avatar *ngIf="(nextLaunch$ | async)?.links?.patch?.small !== null" [style.backgroundImage]="'url('+(nextLaunch$ | async)?.links?.patch?.small+')'" class="example-header-image">
</div>
```

This works perfectly and the avatar is set as expected, however I have I get an error in the browser console:

```
GET http://localhost:4200/null 404 (Not Found)
```

Any ideas to get rid of the error?

### More Info..

The api works well and my service returns data as expected.
The avater image is displayed without any problem.
My only issue is the error that appears on the browser console.
I had done some research and saw that using async pipe could be the cause of the issue but I prefer this rather than subscribe method.

TIA.

Comment: Please provide more details. Does Your Service return Data??

Comment: @JensonMJohn Yes my service prvide data. As indicated above, it works perfectly....the avatar is dispayed so there are no compiler error.. Only the browser shows that skip trace error. Kindly unvote down so that I can get some help.

Comment: @JensonMJohn I added more info that you may need in the question

Comment: @Pac0 Yes I am certain. When I comment out this div the error is not there anymore. Also when I replace div with img tag it does not show this error, however this is not a prefered method.

Comment: @Pac0 check my edits on the quiz

Comment: This is why you don't put so much logic in the template - it makes debugging _very difficult_. Instead of all this `='url('+(nextLaunch$ | async)?.links?.patch?.small+')'"` assign it a variable in your controller. Then, don't use the `DomSanitizer` and `[style.backgroundImage]` but instead [set a CSS class](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass), which is more idiomatic. That said, you need to show us an `http.get()` (probably in `spacexService.getNextLaunch()`) which is triggering your error. Maybe?

Comment: ok, thanks for feedback, I agree with your research result by the way, the async pipe is probably not to be used like that.  I would create a `public smallPatchUrl: string` (or other correct type), use `this.spacexService.getNextLaunch().subscribe(x => this.smallPatchUrl = x.links.patch.small)` (maybe add null checks like `if(x && x.links && x.links.patch)` and use `*ngIf="this.smallPatchUrl"` and similar use for other 'url' attribute.

Comment: @msanford Thank you for your take. Initially I was using a [ngClass] binder but it gave me the same error in the console **however the image avatar is displayed as expected,** in both cases. My only problem is the error that is in the console, in both cases that appears not to be related to compiler errors. This is the method in the service `getNextLaunch(): Observable<SpacexNext> {
    return this.http.get<SpacexNext>(BASE_URL + 'launches/next');
  }`

Comment: @Pac0 thank you for the approach bur after changing to that it now throws a different error. `GET http://localhost:4200/undefined 404 (Not Found)`.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to be more precise: `*ngIf="this.smallPatchUrl" [style.backgroundImage]="url(this.smallPatchUrl)"`

Comment: Thank you @Pac0 this worked but I changed  it to `[style.backgroundImage]="'url('+this.smallPatchUrl+')'"`. Thank you so much! No more skip trace errors

Comment: ah, yes, I forgot the quotes! I'll write a proper answer to summarize.

Answer (score 2):

The `async` pipe is not well suited to be used in this way.

I'd suggest to use an intermediate variable in your component code, to hold the result of your asynchronous operation

```
public smallPatchUrl: string;
```

(I assume this url is of type `string`, adapt if necessary).

In your `ngOnInit` use:

```
this.spacexService.getNextLaunch().subscribe(x => {
  if (x && x.links && x.links.patch) {
    this.smallPatchUrl = x.links.patch.small;
  }
});
```

in your template code, you can use for your component:

```
*ngIf="this.smallPatchUrl" [style.backgroundImage]="'url(' + this.smallPatchUrl + ')'"
```

This way, your component will never use `this.smallPatchUrl` when it is `null` or `undefined`.